# How can I have "rsyslogd" start automatically after a reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I'm running an Ubuntu based distro

```
Linux version 4.1.18-ipipe (ubuntu1604@ubuntu1604) (gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.9.3-13ubuntu2)
```

When this system boots up, `rsyslogd` is not running. So any C programs that call `syslog(...)` do not report any information. The simple fix to this is to SSH into the system and issue an `rsyslogd` on the terminal.

Is there a standard way to have this utility start up automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Is the distribution systemd-based (ubuntu should be, but I am unfamiliar with this one)?

If that is so,

```
 systemctl enable rsyslog
```

ought to do the trick.

Comment: I'm somewhat inclined to think it's not systemd based, as syslog calls would be going to the journal if so. That or @Izzo isn't aware of the journal.

Comment: @phemmer I don't really understand the journal and how it interacts with syslog.. so i might be missing something on my end.

Comment: Looks like no systemctl on my machine: -bash: systemctl: command not found

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird, as Linaro 4.9 is using `systemd`.

First check if the systemd package is

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep systemd
```

If not then install it by hands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemd
```

But if it does it might be damaged, so you may try to reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd
```

After that you should be able to *enable* (autostart) rsyslog as LSerni stated:

```
systemctl enable rsyslog
```